# 2 different m3u for 2 different browser reaction

Tags: google-chrome, m3u

I want to integrate a player for a nicecast shoutcast on my website using m3u, and possibly like this one i found on the internet (or a better if you have one, I already tried jwplayer):

http:// annela plan tine.free.fr/ live.off-1.m3u

Here what I see when I open the other m3u on chrome, but i cant inspect it

For the moment I only have acces to a local broadcast adress : http:// 78.206.140.88:8000/listen.m3u

Here what I see for my adress image, with a browser like camino it's going to download the m3u and broadcast a live stream from itunes...

Thank for you help